# Linux console keyboard handler

Tags: c, linux, console, keyboard

Is it possible to write a C program which works in XFCE's terminal until the user hits Esc-key? If yes, how?

Comment: what do you want to happen after the user hits the Esc key?

Comment: I'm planning to write one program which computes the optimal solution to one particular problem. It should output the best possible solution it has found thusfar. I don't know any good algorithm to the problem so I need to find random numbers which satisfies the problem. As this might take months, it would be nice to interrupt the calculation whenever I like to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you look into [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), an API which is typically used to implement that kind of keyboard-reading in terminal/console applications. There should be no need to do this in a platform-dependent manner.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is pressing Ctrl-C in the terminal window. Your application will stop immediately or You can handle the event with a SIGINT signal handler.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile int exit_loop;

void sig_hnd( void ){ exit_loop=1; }

int main(void){
  signal( SIGINT, (void (*)(int))sig_hnd );

  for( exit_loop=0; !exit_loop; ){
    puts( "do some work" );
    sleep(1);
  }

  puts( "\nend of work\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the wrong question.  Why are you using an interactive terminal at all for a long-running process?  Why not just run as a daemon and log the "best" solution at regular intervals?  The terminal is for interactive use by a human being.  There are better ways to handle software that must run for "months".

Answer (score 0):

Switch the terminal to the [non-canonical mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Canonical-or-Not)